# Inside a pandas dataframe table that I open in a .h5 (h5py) file, how can I remove rows from it?

Tags: python, pandas, h5py

So I am opening my `h5` file in a Python shell as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_hdf('/...mapping_trade_type/BBG002RRB_L3.h5', 'quote')
```

Now when I do `file[:]` there are over 600,000 rows of data, and I would like to delete most of them.

I try something like:

```
file = file.drop(file.index[5:643368])
```

Now when I print `file`, I get the remaining 5 rows in the table, which is exactly what I want.

But when I exit the Python shell, re-enter it, and open up the `quote` table above, there are 643368 rows again.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to export the data, you're currently working on a copy of it

Comment: AHh okay, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your file with [`to_hdf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html), assigning to the same key:

```
df = pd.read_hdf('/...mapping_trade_type/BBG002RRB_L3.h5', 'quote')

(df.drop(file.index[5:643368])
   .to_hdf('/...mapping_trade_type/BBG002RRB_L3.h5', 'quote')
)
```

Comment: Perfect, that does it. But one other thing - when I do the above, it only exports the `quote` table. If I have many other tables in the files, is there a way to export everthing?

Comment: @kfsopdf yo'ure welcome. In doubt, don't hesitate to make a backup of the file before modifying it ;)

Comment: @kfsopdf not sure I understand your updated comment. This will only update `quote` since you only modified that one. The other keys will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

save the data by adding the following code to the end of your code

```
file.to_hdf('/...mapping_trade_type/BBG002RRB_L3_modified.h5', key='quote', mode='w')
```

Comment: not sure if `mode='w'` is the most appropriate, this would delete the existing file and exiting keys if any other than `'quote'`

Comment: Yepp that is an issue, but it works

Comment: `r+` does it! Thanks for the above though - super helpful suggestion